# Stop synchronizing hex view with disassembly view in IDA

Tags: ida, tools

Recently IDA started to synchronize the hex dump with disassembly view. Even if I disable this through right click, it gets reseted every debug session. I also tried to save the desktop with the synchronization disabled, but it gets enabled again after session restart...

How can I stop IDA from synchronizing these views?

I have no plugins that could cause this behavior.

Comment: Which version of IDA are you using? Just checked it on IDA 6.8 on Windows and it did not reproduce.

Comment: 6.6, Windows virtual machine on Linux host.

Comment: You can play with  ./cfg/ida.cfg ... 

Try replace  ./cfg/ida.cfg with default config.

Answer (score 1):

In IDA 7.3 you can just close and reopen the hex view (or IDA view). This causes the hex view to stop synchronizing to the address of the disassembly.

Revert and synchronize using Windows->Reset desktop.